# Fama Macbeth Regression in R: the correct code

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

I want to run a Fama-MacBeth regression in R. My dataset has a few independent variables and date and ticker variables. I have run a code as follows: prepared two codes but their output is different. Which one should I go with? DummyDIV is the multiplication of dummy and DIV. Dummy takes the same value for each tock at month t but it changes depending on the date.

```
pmg1 <- pmg(nextreturn ~ DIV+marketreturn+value+bookmarket+dummyDIV, panel_data, index=c("ticker","date"))
```

or

```
fmb_model1 <- plm(nextreturn ~ DIV+marketreturn+value+bookmarket+bookmarket+dummyDIV, data = panel_data, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
```

I expected them to yield the same results but coefficients are
different.

| ticker | date | nextreturn | DIV | marketreturn | value | bookmarket | dummy | dummyDIV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2002-01-31 | .3 | .3 | .3 | .31 | .05 | 0 | 0 |
| abc | 2002-03-31 | .4 | .5 | .5 | .33 | .03 | 0 | 0 |
| abc | 2002-05-31 | .3 | .6 | .6 | .34 | .02 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz | 2002-01-31 | .1 | .8 | .3 | .41 | .2 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz | 2002-03-31 | .05 | .1 | .5 | .42 | .1 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz | 2002-05-31 | .01 | .3 | .6 | .49 | .5 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz | 2005-05-31 | .01 | .4 | .5 | .55 | .7 | 1 | 0.1 |

Comment: You're more likely to find someone able to help if you include a reproducible example. Can you share a sample of your data using `dput()`?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post accordingly

Comment: You are estimating two different types of models, so same results cannot be expected.